# How to set default value for spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my application I want use `Spinner` and for this a use this **library** : [enter link description here](https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner)

I get array list from server with this code :

```
InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
Call<StringListDataResponse> call = api.getGetAggregationGenres();

call.enqueue(new Callback<StringListDataResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<StringListDataResponse> call, Response<StringListDataResponse> response) {
        if (response.body().getData() != null) {
            spinner.setItems(response.body().getData());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<StringListDataResponse> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Spinner selected Item code:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {

            @Override public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, String item) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked " + item, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    });
```

but I want set default value for this spinner. 
First show my default value, when selected item show this item from list.

how can I it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this

```
spinner.setSelection(position);//to set default values
```

To get selected value use this

```
spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

Hi in your library you can use this

```
spinner.setSelectedIndex(2);
```

Comment: Yes for that you need to set particular position of spinner

Comment: below this line add my code     spinner.setItems(response.body().getData());     spinner.setSelection(1);

Comment: Spinner contains list of items when you setSelection(position) it will set that postion value as default value

Comment: No no my friend, I want first show "all items" in spinner. when users select the items set item selected instead of "all items" text. I want first show "all items" in spinner. how can I it?

Comment: Actually can u clarify your requirement so that i can help you

Comment: my friend, I want get items from server and show it into spinner. but I should use see "all items" but "all items" not send to me from server!  I should first show "all items" when user select item form server such as item1, item2, item 3 or ... set item item1 instead of "all items" ! but I should add "all items" to spinner and this "all items" not send to me from server.

Comment: please help me my friend

Comment: I can solve this but little confused about your requirment

Comment: I get this items from server : item1, item2, item3 and other items ... . ok ?! and when run application show item1 in spinner. I want first show "all items", and when users select on items set this items instead of "all items" . I want add "all items" to first and default item. when users on items set this item instead of "all item" . how can I add this "all item" to first and default value.

Comment: spinner.performClick();   use this to open all the list

Comment: Hi in your library you can use this     spinner.setSelectedIndex(2);